# I need to merge entries with a single table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Have to get this result for the following problem in mysql

For example this table contains, values for columns `month`, `amt1`, `amt2`, `amt3`;
if `amt1` has values then `amt2` and `amt3` will be `null` and similarly for `amt2` and `amt3`.
All columns are `VARCHAR`

But there is a possibility of first row or similar rows for value in month column containing `amt1` without null

might be

equal for the first or similar rows for value in month column containing `amt2` without null

and so on....

How to get a result like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
month           |      amt1     |      amt2     |      amt3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
january - 2013       1000          null             null
january - 2013       null          2000             null
February - 2013       1000          null             null

January - 2013        null        2000             null
February - 2013       null        2000             null

March - 2013          null          null             3000
January - 2013          null          null           3000
January - 2013          20          null           null

February- 2013          null          30           null
March- 2013             null        null           40
March- 2013             null        5000           null
March- 2013             null        50             null
```

---

So the result table should sum-up the available amounts in that particular month, if null exists it should return 0

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
month           |      amt1     |      amt2     |      amt3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
January - 2013     1020              2000            0
February - 2913    1000              2030            3000
March - 2013       0                 5050            3040


-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is another problem you didn't point to, the `February - 2013` is different than `February- 2013` and `March - 2013` than `March- 2013`. Are they entered in the table like this?

Comment: no those were similar

Comment: Question - does your output need to appear in chronological order?

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `SUM`, `SUBSTRING` and `COALESCE` and `LOCATE` function

A simple and fast query with the advice of [David Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/david-wallace) is as follows.

```
 SELECT 
 month,
 COALESCE(SUM(amt1),0) as amt1,
 COALESCE(SUM(amt2),0) as amt2,
 COALESCE(SUM(amt3),0) as amt3
 From 
 Table1
 GROUP BY
 REPLACE(month,' ', '');
```

working demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35547/27

Comment: This won't work if there's more than one year of data.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWallace modified the result

Comment: This is nice, Anamika, and I've now given you an upvote.  But did you consider just making the last bit `GROUP BY REPLACE(month, ' ', '')` - this has the same effect, is more readable, and is most likely faster.

Comment: Thanks its really faster, my query was taking 1 min and after what you suggested it just took 25 secs, please check if this is correct http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35547/25 will modify the ans

Comment: No, no, you don't need two expressions in the group by clause.  Just one; exactly as I wrote it in my earlier comment.  So you're actually grouping the month and year together.  Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR to number conversion should be implicit. But if needed you can explicitly cast as `CAST(amt, DECIMAL(p, s))`. Why don't you try a simple aggregation like this,

```
SELECT 
month,
SUM (amt1),
SUM (amt2),
SUM (amt3)
From Table
Group By month
```

Comment: can you elaborate the issue you are facing?